# Flutter - How to create a checkbox container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want containers with an image and the containers should have the option of selecting and unselecting like a checkbox. How to achieve this?

[image: This is how I want it]

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 5, right: 5),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Color(0xffececec),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 60.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: 
                      Image(
                    width: 120,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      "images/logo.png",
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stack` widget to show the checkmark on top. Create a variable that will control selected index/item.

```dart
 border: Border.all(
            width: 1,
            color: i == selectedIndex
                ? Colors.purple : Color(0xffececec),
                  ),
```

Test snippet

```dart
class CheckBT3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBT3({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckBT3> createState() => _CheckBT3State();
}

class _CheckBT3State extends State<CheckBT3> {
  int? selectedIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //using only single MaterialApp on top level
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = i;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 5, right: 5),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 1,
                              color: i == selectedIndex
                                  ? Colors.purple
                                  : Color(0xffececec),
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Text(i.toString()),
                            if (i == selectedIndex)
                              Positioned(
                                  right: 4,
                                  top: 4,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.check_circle,
                                    color: Colors.purple,
                                  ))
                          ],
                        )

                        // child: Image(
                        //   width: 120,
                        // image: AssetImage(
                        //   "images/logo.png",
                        // ),
                        // ),

                        ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But four containers should have four different images. Where to create images?

Comment: create a list of image path `List<String> images = [, , , ]`and use like `AssetImage(images[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Hi @priya you need to use Stack instead of Column. Please try this code:-

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 5, right: 5),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 1,
                  color: Color(0xffececec),
                ),
                borderRadius: const 
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
            child:Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: 
                  Image(
                width: 120,
                height:120
                image: AssetImage(
                  "images/logo.png",                    
              ),
              Positioned(top:10, right:10, 
               child:Image(
                width: 30,
                image: AssetImage(
                  "add here your check image",
                ))
      ],
    ),
```

Please let me know if you still face any issue